# Django - Link to download CSV in template

Tags: python, django, django-models

Trying to figure out how to correctly create a download link to a csv file on my template.

## Views.py

```
#this is the view that shows the html page (all queries work)
def admin_view(request, mysite):
    context = dict()
    context["mysite"] = mysite.upper()
    group = whid.lower() + "-group"
    user = request.user.get_username()
    authorized = is_authorized(user, group)
    end_time = timezone.now()
    start_time = end_time.replace(day=1, hour=00, minute=00, second=00)
    error_message = ("You are not authorized to be in this page.")
    context['data'] = CheckIn.objects.filter(Date__range=(start_time, end_time))
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    context['today'] = today
    context['first_day'] = today.replace(day=1, hour=00, minute=1)

    #Calling the csv function here
    context['response'] = export_search_csv(start_time, end_time) 

    if (authorized):
        return render(request, 'mykiosk/admin.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(error)


#function to grab and create csv
def export_search_csv(start_time, end_time):
    data = CheckIn.objects.filter(Date__range=(start_time, end_time))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['id', 'EmpID', 'BarID', 'Username', 'Type', 'Liability', 'Date'])
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item.id, item.EmpID, item.BarID, item.Username, item.Type, item.Liability, item.Date])
    return response
```

## Template

```
<a href="{{ response}}">export to csv</a>
```

Then all I get is a `<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/csv">` when trying to access the link. I'm missing something, I'm just not sure what. Due to internal company regulations, I can't use the `djqscsv` library either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing it wrong way. Rather than sending it via context, you should convert your `export_search_csv` method to a view and use it from template. For example:

```
def export_search_csv(request, start_date, end_date):
    data = CheckIn.objects.filter(Date__range=(datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['id', 'EmpID', 'BarID', 'Username', 'Type', 'Liability', 'Date'])
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item.id, item.EmpID, item.BarID, item.Username, item.Type, item.Liability, item.Date])
    return response


def admin_view(request, mysite):
    ...
    context['start_date'] = startdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    context['end_date'] = enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    ...
```

In template:

```
<a href="{% url 'export_search_csv' start_date end_date %}">export to csv</a>
```

Add new **url** for new view:

```
path('your_path/<str:start_date>/<str:end_date>/', export_search_csv, name='export_search_csv'),
```

Comment: this is smart. I used same logic to pass an args to a function in order to dynamically create many csv export without duplicating anything in views.py